# List calendar days on Excel as a list for Attendance Record

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

As stated, I want to make an Attendance Record.

And if my question is repeated, kindly direct me to the said page.

Is it possible to apply two cells which can be edited; let's say E3 cell as Month and F3 as Year, and by just changing those 2 cells, the dates will appear for the whole month on a column. For example:

[image]

So if I change it to August 2016, the data in column B should change according to the month and year inputted at E3 and F3.

[image]

If there is a way, I hope you could brief me through the whole process because I am not good with formulas and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll create 31 potential date cells and display a date only if it exists.

1. Fill cells A5 to A35 with numbers from 1 to 31. You can type 1 in cell A5, 2 in cell A6, then select both cells and drag down the little square at the bottom right corner of the selection area (drag until you reach cell A35).

   [image]
2. Enter this formula in cell B5:

   `=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(A5&"-"&$E$3&"-"&$F$3)),"",DATEVALUE(A5&"-"&$E$3&"-"&$F$3))`
3. If you see a number instead of a date in cell B5, change the cell format to `Short Date` or any date format that you prefer.
4. Autofill the next 30 cells by double clicking the little square at the bottom right corner of A5.
5. You can now hide column A by right clicking the column header and choosing `Hide`.

**The formula explained**

The formula uses the `DATEVALUE` function to convert a text date into a real Excel date. We use the day value from column A and concatenate it with the month and year in cells E3 and F3. For example `24-October-2016`. The dollar signs in $E$3 and $F$3 indicate we want these specific cells, so when you autofill the formula, all the cells in column B will still reference E3 and F3.

The `ISERROR` function checks if `DATEVALUE` returns an error. If it does (for example if the text is `30-February-2016`), then we place an empty value in that cell. Otherwise we use the date produced by `DATEVALUE`.

Comment: You can eliminate the helper column by referring to the row number with adjustment for position (if B5 is the 1st row, ROW()-4 instead of the A5 reference).  Also, you can eliminate the redundant DATEVALUE() by using IFERROR() instead of IF(ISERROR()).